# A question regarding a theorem of Erdos and Hajnal

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following theorem of Erdos and Hajnal:

Definition.  For any set $x$, a function $f$ is called ${\omega} $-Jonsson iff $f$: $^{\omega}x$ $\rightarrow$ x and whenever $y$$\subseteq$$x$ and |$y$|=|$x$|, $f^"$$^{\omega}y$=$x$ ($f^"$$^{\omega}x$=range ($f$$\upharpoonright$$^{\omega}x$)).

Theorem.  For every infinite cardinal $\lambda$, there is an  $\omega$-Jonnson function over $\lambda$.

The proof of this theorem uses the Axiom of Choice.  In $ZFC$, can one provide a 'simple' proof of this theorem in which the Axiom of Choice (or a sentence equivalent to it) is an explicit step in the proof?

Comment: Yes. Do you know any of the proofs? Is there a specific one you have in mind for which this is not evident?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo:  yes, a couple, in particular the one found in found in Kunen's original paper, and the one  found in the Solovay, Reinhardt, and Kanamori paper "Strong Axioms of Infinity and Elementary Embeddings" (their version of the theorem in the one used in my question), both of which (to me, at least) do not explicitly use $AC$ or any known equivalence thereof as a step in their proofs.  If you would give me the shortest, simplest proof that uses $AC$ as an explicit step in the proof as an answer, I'll definitely accept the answer.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Thomas: See the second sentence of the proof in that paper: the enumeration of $[\omega]^\omega\times\omega$ in type $2^\omega$ well-orders it, so this already requires $\mathsf{AC}$. You’re appealing to $\mathsf{AC}$ again when you pick the sequences $s_\alpha$. And I suspect that the existence of the maximal collection $\mathscr{S}$ requires it; certainly that’s the easiest way to justify its existence.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott:  That makes a lot of sense.  Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas: You’re welcome.